# Show slideshow with pictures and videos

Tags: windows-7, linux, software-rec, image-viewer

I'm mostly a Linux guy but I don't think the software I'm looking for is available in Linux so I ask this presumable easy question for those of you that knows Windows.

The thing I want to do is to just take a SD-card from a camera, pop it into the computer and then show a slideshow with images AND VIDEOS. I need to be able to manually step between the pics/videos with the keyboard and I don't want the hassle of using something like ffdiaporama (which otherwise is a great app) or any video editor. The program should, of course, also be able to show the slideshow in fullscreen.

Would the standard image viewer in Win 7 allow me to do this? I don't got access to a windows computer right now so can't test it. Or is there any other good and free programs that lets me do this?

And if someone would knows of any software for Linux that can handle this, that would be even better. But I don't believe it exist, I tried google and asked a question on askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mix of video and pictures seem to be a bit tricky, so I fear there doesn't seem to be anything supporting what you're looking for.

With the [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/) you can create a playlist to which you add videos and pictures. However, pictures are only displayed for 1 second (I couldn't find a way to increase that).

My best bet then would be to create a [LibreOffice Impress](http://www.libreoffice.org/) presentation with the content, put it on the USB stick and start that. I couldn't find a list of supported video formats. :-(

On Windows you can use [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) with it's multimedia plugins (see plugins link on their homepage).

Comment: Oh, I know about Irfan, that seems like the best solution so far for me. I'll try it when I get some time :) I'm also thinking about writting something in Python for linux. It seems strange to me, would'nt this be a very common thing to do?

Comment: Well, I thought so too. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Just download [Windows Live Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-live/essentials-home) and install the [Photo Gallery](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-live/photo-gallery-get-started). Different from the stock photo viewer in Windows 7, this photo gallery can actually play videos and also does that in slideshows.

Caveat: For a slideshow you usually want a certain order and this is easy if you sort it in Explorer, select all files and open it with the Live Photo Gallery. This only works if you choose yes when you open Photo Gallery on its own the first time and it's asking you whether you want to open JPG,.. with it by default. Otherwise you can only open a single picture with it via Open With in explorer. Don't ask me why. If you don't want the default stuff, then you can alternatively open Photo Gallery and use its integrated file explorer for sorting etc.

Answer (score 1):

The best bet for you would be to use picasa. And uploading and customizing your images on it is very easy, you just have to add the folder where your images are present.Also I think you can install picasa on ubuntu.
The standard win 7 image viewer wont work for your slideshow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GNOME's [gThumb](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/gthumb) image browser. It can sort media by recording time (EXIF) and present both photos and videos in a folder in the same interface / slideshow.
gThumb is available in most Linux distributions, e.g., in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install gThumb
```

It seems not to be available for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I Know this is an old Post. But If some one is looking for Slideshow that has both video and Image and mostly from command line, also video will be shown as image with play button an user can click play to play movie.

[Feh](http://man.finalrewind.org/1/feh/#x464f524d4154x20x53504543494649455253) is the tool.

And for Video alone I used VLC.

Taken snapshot of the movie using [VLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_create_thumbnails/) and had naming convention to Identify that this is a movie and file name of original movie

Used image Magic to compose Play button to image

Feh Configured Action button 0 ([Return Key]) to execute a shell program which is playing in VLC full screen and stop after playing.

Answer (score 1):

Mix of picture and video does seem to be tricky.

IrfanView worked for me.

Hardware Media Players don't seem to do it. In particular the Micca Speck, the Incredisonic, the Blusmart, and KDLINKS HD720 mini-hardware media players do NOT do it.  That is, as of 6/2/2015 because they come out with new versions of these little boxes every year or so.

How do I know?

- I purchased the Micca Speck and tried it.
- A friend had the Incredisonic (which btw had the EXACT same menu system as the Micca Speck) and I tried it.
- For the Blusmart I asked on Amazon's question feature and someone who owned it actually tried it.
- And for the KDLINKS I also asked in Amazon and a distributor answered.

I also tried on a recent Android tablet the Gallery app and Picasa.

- Gallery you had to click on the video.
- Picasa didn't see the videos.

So following recommendations here I downloaded **IrfanView** today (thru LiberKey (a portable application launcher, although i think i prefer PortableApps.com *without* the launcher)).

`File -> Slideshow` opens a dialog box with copious options.

It only played one of the formats of videos i had: .wmv
That was disappointing but I can use FormatFactory or iWisoft video converter to convert them, so I'm not that worried. I also assume with some codec/plugin work i could get other formats to work in IrfanView.

In particular IrfanView lets you pick the pictures you want, including all of them.

You can select a **mix of pictures and videos.**

IrfanView lists what you have selected in another box where you can **control the order.**

It **auto-plays** videos, and auto-moves on to the next file, whether picture or video.

Here are its other features that I have seen people ask for in various threads as I was searching for an answer to this question:

- There is a **random** order option.
- You can **Loop** the slide show.
- You can set the **automatically advance** after the number of **seconds** you choose (default 5 sec), or after **mouse/keyboard** input.
- It defaults to showing little green text in the upper left with folder/file and index eg: [3/15] meaning 3rd file out of 15 total.
- It can include **subdirectories**, or not, when doing "Add All"
- It can **remember last file index** on exit, and so start where it left off, or not, and start from the beginning.
- It can show or hide **mouse cursor.**
- It can **close IrfanView** after last file (presuming you don't loop)
- It defaults to play in **fullscreen** mode, but has a windows option.

So given this program works, my plan is to purchase an HP Stream for about $200 USD install IrfanView on it and connect to its HDMI port o make my own media player box.  I know people do this with Kodi/XBMC on a raspberry PI or similar, and that seems like more fun, but my plan seems easier.

**EDIT:** I executed this plan and it worked nicely.  Couple things:

IrfanView has command line options can can start in slideshow mode by specifying a folder, eg `/slideshow=G:\path\to\folder`
I tried that. It works, but it does not have the `Include subdirectories (for 'Add all')` feature when used that way. So you only get the pictures in that *actual* dir, none from subdirs of that dir.

However, there is a `Save filenames as TXT file` option. So you can manually use `Add all` with `Include subdirectories (for 'Add all')` checked to add all media files in the current and all subdirectories. You can then sort/order them, or include others or exclude some. Then you can `Save filenames as TXT file` to some filename.txt file.

Once I had that file I created a desktop shortcut in which I modified the target to append `/slideshow=d:\filename.txt` ie that file i made. Now, double-clicking on that shortcut's icon starts the slideshow with 1 click (well, 1 double-click ;)

I did buy an HP Stream. It was $188 at Walmart online plus sales tax but free shipping.  I found it a capable machine. Not fast. But not painfully slow. There's lag in many things i do, but only 1-2 sec usually.  It has 17GB free disk space (technically SSD space)--very liming, but with an SD Card slot which I am using for the pictures.

I used Windows normally to change closing the lid behavior to "do nothing". But even when connected to an external monitor, closing the lid stops the slideshow.  So the lid has to stay open all the time--even with an external monitor. Of course i changed power options to never sleep and never turn off the display when plugged in.

Also, I have the TV that this is connected to via its HDMI port plugged into an outlet controlled by a wall switch. When I flip the switch off, the TV goes off, and the HP Stream keeps playing the IrfanView slideshow. When I flip the switch back on, the TV comes back on, and the HP Stream (running Windows 8.1) recognizes it and starts displaying to it again, with out user intervention. That's nice. It does mean the HP Stream goes on playing all night long while the place is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Drad & Drop all photos & videos to standard Windows Media Player and enjoy! (works in windows 8, it auto rotates videos from iPhone)